# Append relationship count with each model in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

in my app an address can have many places, now I want to retrieve all address with the count of places appended to EACH address, how can I do this with Eloquent?

```
$address= Address::with('places')->get();
```

Thanks in davance

Answer (score 3):

Use Eloquent's `withCount()`:

```php
$address = Address::withCount('places')->get();
```

It will return the count of each model's related rows with a field

```php
$address->places_count
```

Official documenation for `withCount` can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

```
$addresses = App\Models\Address::withCount('places')->get();
```

then get the count of places by `{relation}_count`.

```
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
  echo $address->places_count;
}
```